# Add additional text to email template container

Tags: magento2, email-templates

This is my system.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="afteremail" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Label</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="afteremail" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>After Email</label>
        <tab>afteremail</tab>
        <resource>Module_Vendor::afteremail_config</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Display Text</label>
                <comment>This text will display on the all transactional emails.</comment>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

And config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <afteremail>
        <general>
            <display_text>Hello World</display_text>
        </general>
    </afteremail>
</default>
</config>
```

Helper Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

const XML_PATH_AFTEREMAIL = 'afteremail/';

public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
    );
}

public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
{

    return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_AFTEREMAIL .'general/'. $code, $storeId);
}

}
```

As well as Plugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\DefaultTemplate;

class AddText
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
 */
protected $serializer;

protected $helperData;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $helperData
) {
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
}

/**
 * @param DefaultTemplate $template
 * @param $result
 */
public function afterExecute(DefaultTemplate $template, $result)
{
    $displayText = $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('display_text');
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response */
    $response = $template->getResponse();
    $body = $this->serializer->unserialize($response->getBody());

    $body['template_text'] .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $displayText;

    $response->representJson(
        $this->serializer->serialize($body)
    );
}
}
```

For now, additional text displays out of email container.
I want to achieve that it displays in the container.
Any suggestions on how to do that will be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You can try another way to do that. Create a custom variable from Magento Admin panel, insert your text on that custom variable. then create a new footer template and insert your custom variable on the new footer email template. Please see this URL https://bsscommerce.com/blog/customize--magento-2-footer-template

Comment: This method partly solves my task, but the idea is to edit text in the config tab.
I suppose there is no option to update variable text from config tab.